# Display Sum at the end of the table in JSP page

Tags: jsp, jstl

SL  Amt
1   932.0
2   479.0
3   531.0

JSP sample-

```
<c:forEach items="${listOfData}" var="data">
     <c:set var="sl" value="<%=sl = sl + 1%>" />
     <tr>
         <td style="text-align: center">
             <c:out value="${sl}"/>
         </td>
         <td>
             <label name="amount"  path="amount"  Style="font-size:10px;" >${data.Amt}<label/>
         </td>
         </td>
     </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Expected Output:

SL            Amt
1            932.0
2            479.0
3            531.0
Total (3)    1942.0

Comment: What is your question? What does means 'SL Amt'? What is the content of `listOfData`?

Comment: listOfData contains the values of the table

Comment: Can you provide example values?

Comment: The values come from API response but I need to add a ROW as sum of total value in the JSP page